# how to show the hidden div over other div's in middle of page instead of overflowing

Tags: html, css, overflow, offset

I have few divs which have child table attached to it, and these are visible as we click on on these divs.

But the Divs on the right hand side of the page the table that appears overflows from the screen, where as i want it to be displyed on the left on the empty part of screen where there are other divs.

I am not sure if i am able to explain this so here are screenshots.

How it appears now

[image: How it is visible Now]

I would want it to appear for each table like this but as of now it happens only for the center divs

[image: How i will want it to look for every div]

My Html

```
<div *ngIf="visibleTournament">
  <div class = "row">
    <div *ngFor="let entry of competitionTeams | keys">
      <div class="col-md-4" (mouseleave)= "entry.hideme = false">
        <div>
          <div (click) = "entry.hideme = !entry.hideme" >
            <div class = "groupBox"><div class="placed"><h3><span class = "label label-warning">Group - {{entry.key}}</span></h3></div></div>
          </div>
          <div class="well box" [hidden] = "!entry.hideme">
            <table class="table" width="100%">
              <thead class="thead-inverse">
              <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Team</th>
                <th>Played Games</th>
                <th>Points</th>
                <th>Goals</th>
                <th>GA</th>
                <th>GD</th>
              </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
              <tr *ngFor="let subValue of entry.value">
                <th scope="row">{{subValue.rank}}</th>
                <td><img class="img-thumbnail small" src="{{subValue.crestURI}}">{{subValue.team}}</td>
                <td>{{subValue.playedGames}}</td>
                <td>{{subValue.points}}</td>
                <td>{{subValue.goals}}</td>
                <td>{{subValue.goalsAgainst}}</td>
                <td>{{subValue.goalDifference}}</td>
              </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Corresponding Css

```
.avatar{
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  border: none;
}

.inline{
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px 20px;
}

.check{
  min-width: 500px;
}

.selector{
  cursor: pointer;
}
.placed{
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.box{
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  background: #ccffda;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  width: 600px;
  border: darkgray 1px solid;
  z-index: 1;
}


.groupBox{
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  padding: 20px 20px;
  margin: 2px;
  border: darkgray 1px solid;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

th {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.col-md-4{
  margin-bottom: 80px;

}

.fix{
  position: absolute;
}

.group{
  /*background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);*/
}
table th {
  font-weight: bolder;
  /*color:#49fb35;*/
}

.small{
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  border: none;
}
```

Very new to css concepts Please help

Comment: Remove the well from the class for well box

Comment: Did but still the same, I donot want to hide behind the scroll bar instead place in the center of screen like the screen shot

Comment: Add a X and y to the box class

Comment: Can you please elaborate sorry i am really new to such css concepts

Comment: X: 500px; Y: 200px; an example. Depends where u want to put it

Answer (score 0):

Every thing is going as supposed to. you need to give the 'box' class 
a max-width of 100% like that: 
 `.box{max-width: 100%`}. 
 and if your well comes from bootstrap perhaps you will need to add an !important;

But then, you will have other problems re-design the table to fit the new width.

Comment: This will only help in showing the box , but i want to show my box in the middle of the screen like for the screen shot for all elements , instead of me getting a scroll bar as i am getting now

Comment: show us in a picture how exactly do you want it to be located

Comment: like the second screenshot attached to the question for ever div element i click i want the table to appear there or some where close to that

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the code, opened div's right side must be 0 of its relative parent. I would do it with javascript just by simply adding some class to the every 3rd div of row which is located in the right side like below.

```
$('.mainDiv).each(function( index ) {
 if(index%3==0){
   $(this).addClass('right-side');
 }
});
```

and the style of 'right-side' class must be set like

```
.right-side{
  right:0;
}
```

Comment: If i want to move the box up along with right , what can i do to achieve that

Comment: Can you give more information about what you exactly want?

Comment: i want all the hidden boxes to appear in the center like in the second screen shot where i click on middle div ,  fleft right  all hidden table boxes should appear in the middle